# Xtend how to get full path of current working directory

Tags: java, absolute-path, xtend

I have written a grammar that allows the user to input a relative path. (e.g. "../../temp/out/path"

May aim is to get the absolute path based on the input from the user, and the absolute path of the current working directory so that I can also check if the input path is valid or not.

Is there libraries or built in functions that I can use to get the absolute path?
Something similar to C's _getcwd() function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Java has a [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class. You can create one by calling [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) which takes a `String`.  Then you can call `getAbsolutePath()` on it.   You can call it like this:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.io.File;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("relative path");
        String absolutePathString = file.getAbsolutePath();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print a complete absolute path from where your application has initialized.

```
public class JavaApplication1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Working Directory = " +System.getProperty("user.dir"));
   }
}
```